# Object is not fitting into fixed position in board game in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a board game using Unity. This board game uses pyramids as objects and it moves left, right, forward and backward on a board, which has triangular base to fit the pyramid into it. For first three of four moves pyramid seems fitting on triangle exactly. But as I move it ahead, I found that pyramid is not fitting into triangle position exactly. It is a bit moved to outside of pyramid along with moves taken forward. I believe(not sure!) that a floating number is causing this kind of problem but I am not able to find it. This is something driving me craze since past week. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
//forward move
void setObj()
{
    Set_Positions.instance.hitObj.GetComponent<pyramid_manager> ().row++;
    Set_Positions.instance.curObj.parent = null;
    Set_Positions.instance.parentObj.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
    Set_Positions.instance.parentObj.transform.position = Set_Positions.instance.curObj.position;
    Set_Positions.instance.curObj.parent = Set_Positions.instance.parentObj;
    Set_Positions.instance.parentObj.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (110f,Set_Positions.instance.parentObj.transform.eulerAngles.y, Set_Positions.instance.parentObj.transform.eulerAngles.z), 0.5f, 0);
}
```

Comment: If you are using float values for your positions, that might be a problem, yes (floating point imprecision). If you can't make the board using integer values, you could try to round the position of the pyramid after each move, e.g. with modulo (if you have a fixed grid size).

Comment: @GunnarB.Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: Tried. But it is not working. Still pyramid seems rotated from its fixed position.

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D game? Can you post your current code and maybe a screenshot too? This will likely get you some answer...

Comment: @Programmer here you can see image, [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0By0WZMNN0unULXl1dUxvX2N4NGs).

Comment: @Programmer I have added code in description

Comment: Are these affecting all the triangles or some? To be honest, there is something wrong with how you are rotating this but this code is not enough to be what you are doing wrong. For example, no one knows what your `DORotate` function is doing since you didn't post it....

Comment: @Programmer yes it is affecting all the pyramids.

Comment: This sounds crazy but you mean uploading the project and linking it here? You can delete it once I let you know that I've downloaded it. I do understand your problem but this will be though to even suggest a fix without the project itself.

Comment: @Programmer I used `DORotate` for smooth animation.

Comment: Ya but `DORotate` is not a Unity built in API function. We don't know what code is inside it and what the code is doing. That's likely the problem.

Comment: @Programmer I also tried with Unity's default method. It showed the same problem. So I don't think it has anything do with the rotated position of pyramid. what is your mail id?

Comment: Usually don't share my email on public forums. You can upload it to Google Doc then link it here. If you are worried about anyone getting it, make it a rar file with password then upload it to Google Doc. Email me the password to a temporary email I just created `STHelp.aq1@20mail.eu`. Also provide the link to Google Doc.

Comment: @Programmer uploading will take considerable amount of time. Is it convenient if I show you my whole project running on TeamViewer? By the way thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: @Programmer sent you an email on your given id